# Copy a bunch of .wav files, change the content to another .wav sound, but keep the names

Tags: python, batch-file, file-rename, file-copying

I got a folder filled with sounds, and I want to replace all of the sounds to a single sound I have, but I want all the files to keep their original name, would this be possible?

I don't have any idea on how I could do this honestly.

Comment: Get a list of the file names, open each file to write and copy the data of the sound you want to replace with to the open file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this? I am a little confused with the sounds, but tried to understand it.

```
import os, wave, shutil

my_sound = "sound.wav"
my_dir = "/tests/sounds/"

for filename in os.listdir(my_dir):
    if filename.endswith(".wav"):
        file_path = os.path.join(my_dir, filename)
        with wave.open(file_path, 'wb') as test_wave:
            with wave.open(my_sound, 'rb') as original_wave:
                test_wave.setparams(original_wave.getparams())
                test_wave.writeframes(original_wave.readframes(original_wave.getnframes()))
```